# Issues when installing Monit

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, dpkg, monit

I have recently been trying to install Open Media Vault along with exFAT support (exfat-fuse and exFAT-utils), however, when Monit tries to install it returns with the following error:

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  exfat-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exfat-fuse exfat-utils
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 67.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 260 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.datamossa.io/raspbian buster/main armhf exfat-fuse armhf 1.3.0-1 [27.5 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.datamossa.io/raspbian buster/main armhf exfat-utils armhf 1.3.0-1 [40.3 kB]
Fetched 67.7 kB in 2s (32.4 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package exfat-fuse.
(Reading database ... 155288 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../exfat-fuse_1.3.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking exfat-fuse (1.3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package exfat-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking exfat-utils (1.3.0-1) ...
Setting up monit (1:5.26.0-1) ...
Job for monit.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status monit.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript monit, action "start" failed.
● monit.service - LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/monit; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-12-09 12:50:10 AEST; 386ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15158 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/monit start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 09 12:50:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon...
Dec 09 12:50:09 raspberrypi monit[15158]: Starting daemon monitor: monitSegmentation fault
Dec 09 12:50:09 raspberrypi monit[15158]:  failed!
Dec 09 12:50:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monit.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 09 12:50:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 09 12:50:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon.
dpkg: error processing package monit (--configure):
 installed monit package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up exfat-utils (1.3.0-1) ...
Setting up exfat-fuse (1.3.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 monit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

We can obviously see that the control process exited and caused this: 
`Failed to start LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon.`
 However, I have no idea what went wrong and how to fix this. Any ideas on how I could successfully install the Monit Package?